# refactoring PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, refactoring

I encountered the following PL/SQL code(variables modified) at work:

```
PROCEDURE test(i_w IN a.w%type,o_result IN OUT resu_cur_type) IS
BEGIN
    IF i_w IS NULL THEN
      open o_result for SELECT a.x, b.y FROM a,b WHERE a.z=b.z;
    ELSE
      open o_result for SELECT a.x, b.y FROM a,b WHERE a.z=b.z AND a.w=i_w;
    END IF;
END test;
```

I think the above is equivalent to the following:

```
PROCEDURE test(i_w IN a.w%type,o_result IN OUT resu_cur_type) IS
BEGIN
      open o_result for SELECT a.x, b.y FROM a,b WHERE a.z=b.z AND NVL(a.w,1)=NVL(NVL(i_w,a.w),1);
END test;
```

Won't it be the same?. Could somebody please explain is there any reason to use the
original version?. 
Please note that the original cursor is a 50 line query, so refactoring might improve its readability and keep it simple.

Edit:

To address the problem in Kevin Burton's answer, I've updated the WHERE condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if a.w is null you will not select the records

as

```
a.w=NVL(i_w,a.w);
```

will be

```
a.w=NULL
```

Answer (score 6):

As Kevin Burton said, your new query is not equivalent.  This is though:

```
PROCEDURE test(i_w IN a.w%type,o_result IN OUT resu_cur_type) IS
BEGIN
      open o_result for SELECT a.x, b.y FROM a,b
                        WHERE a.z=b.z 
                        AND (i_w IS NULL OR a.w=i_w);
END test;
```

However, the original code may be more efficient as can use an index on a.w when i_w is not null but do something different when it is null - i.e. it tailors the query to the parameters used.

Comment: Thanks Tony. Looks more readable than NVL(). I checked and there aren't any indexes available for a.w. So that shouldn't be a problem unless we create index on the column later on which I doubt we would.

Comment: @digdug: The original code also won't have to worry about bind-variable peeking reducing the cardinality estimate by 95%.  Most of your performance problems will probably be with SQL, not PL/SQL.  In this case you're probably better off reducing one line of SQL than several lines of PL/SQL.  Another alternative is to use dynamic SQL; that may simplify both the PL/SQL and the SQL, but it raises a lot of other issues that must be very carefully considered.

Comment: @jonearles: Thanks. Could you please explain "bind-variable peeking reducing the cardinality estimate by 95%"?